# How do you detect another desktop application if it's installed or even running in MeteorJS?

Tags: meteor, controls, desktop-application

What I'm trying to achieve is after a user logs into the MeteorJS web application, to have it first check if a desktop text editor application is installed. If it is, then secondly have Meteor check whether the text editor is running or not, and if not, run the text editor. Controls, like pressing the "File" menu would be nice and is a bonus from the Meteor app. I'm aiming to make it work for all OS flavors (Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux).

I'm curious as to whether or not there is such a package that will help me get this functionality I need, or if anybody else has done this before?

Comment: I highly doubt that such API exists in any browser, for security and privacy reasons.

Comment: You could take a look at [external protocols](https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/219031308-How-to-launch-external-applications-using-custom-protocols-rock-instead-of-http-), maybe they could help in some cases, but I wouldn't completely rely on them.

Comment: You cannot access on client file system with any browser for security reason. What you ask sound completely impossible to me.

Comment: Can't be done from a browser. You'd have to install a native app.